# Spring Integration error "no output-channel or replyChannel header available"

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-amqp

I am not sure why I am getting the exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
```

Its just a simple IntegrationFlow but not sure what am I missing here in the code below.

```
  @Bean
  Exchange messageExchange() {
    return ExchangeBuilder
        .directExchange("attr")
        .durable(true)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  Queue queue() {
    return QueueBuilder
        .durable("attr_queue")
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  Binding binding() {
    return BindingBuilder
        .bind(queue())
        .to(messageExchange())
        .with("attr_queue")
        .noargs();
  }

  @Bean
  IntegrationFlow deltaFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp
        .inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, queue()))
        .handle(String.class, (payload, headers) -> {
          if (payload.isEmpty()) {
            log.info("Payload empty");
          } else {
            log.info("Payload : " + payload);
          }
          return payload;
        })
        .get();
  }
```

I was trying to get my hands on Spring Integration and was not sure why I am getting this exception. All I'm trying to do is to read from a queue using an `inboundAdapter` and just log it to the console. The code runs fine, but when I publish a message to the queue, I get this exception. Do I have to specify a `replyChannel` or `output-channel` always when using `Amqp` adapters?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, that’s not AMQP Channel Adapter problem. Please, look at your `handle()` - you return something there. And there is nothing afterwards to handle that return. So, where should a reply go? Right, into the `replyChannel` header. But wait , there is no one because there is nothing to wait for the reply - the Channel Adapter is one-way component.

Since you do nothing with the reply and the Framework can’t make an assumption from the configuration phase that you are not going to handle this reply, we just have that exception at runtime. It can’t make that assumption because there is a message channel before that `handle()`, so you may send a message with `replyChannel` header from some other flow and so on. But! Since this is your code and you fully control it you may have an assumption that nobody is going to expect a reply from there and it would be better to stop streaming from this point. For this purpose it would be better to use one-way `MessageHandler` - based `handle()` variant or just return `null` instead of `payload`. You also may use `channel(“nullChannel”)` to stop streaming.

Comment: This is a life saver.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer. I hat the problem in a method annotated with `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputQueue")` that returned something. I changed signature to `void` and exception is not thrown any more.