# How to set expected reply to false using Spring integration DSL. Error no output-channel or replyChannel header available

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Im working with Spring Integration and am working with files. I'm using the provided DSL to process my files. At the end of my integration flow I am outputting the result to a new file using  `Files.outboundGateway(...)` . However I keep getting the following error `no output-channel or replyChannel header available`. According to the post at the bottom of this post the solution is to set the expected reply to false but, how do I do that with the DSL?

Below shows what I'm doing in the last part of my integration flow to write to a file.

```
.handle(Files.outboundGateway(new File(outputFilePath))
                    .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                    .fileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.APPEND)
                    .appendNewLine(true)
                    .fileNameGenerator(m -> m.getHeaders().getOrDefault("file_name", "outputFile") + "_out.txt")
                    
                    )
            .get();
```

[Spring Integration error "no output-channel or replyChannel header available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48069551/spring-integration-error-no-output-channel-or-replychannel-header-available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using an `outboundAdapter()` instead of gateway since you are not going to deal with the writing result and this is the end of your flow:

```
/**
 * Create a {@link FileWritingMessageHandlerSpec} builder for the one-way {@code FileWritingMessageHandler}.
 * @param destinationDirectory the target directory to write files.
 * @return the {@link FileWritingMessageHandlerSpec} instance.
 */
public static FileWritingMessageHandlerSpec outboundAdapter(File destinationDirectory) {
```